# The name of which.min and which.max output the same due to missing value

Tags: r

I have the following data with Korea with a missing value between two columns:

```
canada <- c(100, 0, 100)
korea <- c(100, "", 100)
brazil <- c(100, 90, 100)
fruit <- rbind(canada, korea, brazil)
colnames(fruit) <- c("apple", "orange", "banana")
fruit
```

I need to print the names of fruits from the minimum value to maximum value. I have this:

```
price <- function(val){
  # General Functions ----
  val <- tolower(val)
  myrow <- fruit[val,]
  nation <- tools::toTitleCase(val)

  name.min <- names(myrow)[which.min(c(myrow))]
  name.max <- names(myrow)[which.max(c(myrow))]

    cat(paste0("There is an 'NA' between two columns: ", name.min, " ", name.max))
}
```

The problem is that because there is a missing value between Korea's apple and banana, this is what it prints:

```
> price("korea")
There is an NA between two columns: apple apple
```

I want it to look like this:

```
> price("korea")
There is an NA between two columns? No problem: apple banana
```

Comment: searching for min and max values with prices as characters also seems a problem to me - also both available values for "korea" are the same anyway so min=max

Comment: change "" to NA to define your missing value and modify 100 to 50 for one of the values of korea (to avoid tied) and it will work... problem is not really with the missing value but how you defined the missing value (= as character, converting your entire matrix to character)

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to read into my question. I appreciate it very much. Yes, modifying 100 to 50 would work, but I will have to work with both scores being the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
price <- function(val){
  val <- tolower(val)
  myrow <- fruit[val,]
  nation <- tools::toTitleCase(val)

  name.min <- names(myrow)[which.min(c(myrow))]
  name.max <- names(which(myrow == max(myrow)))

  cat(paste0(name.max))
} 

> price("korea")
apple banana
```

Answer (score 1):

This is ugly but should do what you are looking for:

```
price <- function(x) { 
    temp <- data.frame(val = as.numeric(fruit[rownames(fruit)==x,]),
                    name = colnames(fruit))
    ind <- which(is.na(temp[,1]))
    if (length(ind!=0)) temp <- temp[-ind,]
    temp[order(temp[,1]),2]
}

price("korea")
```